# iOS 16.4+ randomly stops receiving notifications

Tags: ios, blazor, progressive-web-apps, web-push

My Blazor PWA calls azure functions that, among other things, use a push library to send push notifications to clients during gameplay. They always work seamlessly with chrome on PCs. The pushes sometimes work with Safari on IOS 16.4+ and IF they do work, they randomly stop working after a short time.

As an example, I can be in a "match" between a user on my iPhone (safari 16.5) and a user on my PC (Chrome) both utilizing the same PWA. When the safari iOS version stops receiving pushes (seamingly randomly) the PC chrome version continues to receive game-update pushes. I have to believe this is an apple web push issue...?

Is this a known issue anyone else is experiencing? Any fixes out there?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Facing same behaviour with my PWA on iOS 16.4+, you are not alone :D